# what font is used on most Microsoft-made Windows 8 apps?

Tags: fonts, windows-8

take a look at this [image]

what font is used on the left List Box "PC settings" until "Windows Update"?
it sure looks beautiful

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's **Segoe UI**.
More information about typography and fonts in Windows 8 is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx

Comment: BTW: One can use Googles free font "Noto Sans" in your own project. It looks pretty much the same and supports really a lot of signs and symbols. (One is not allowed to use Segoe UI).

Answer (score 13):

Right.  Segoe UI.  But actually a lot of it is **Segoe UI Light** and there is a difference.  If you check out the link on Microsoft site ([Font samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx)) you will see that their samples are all large and the font looks okay like that.
However, it is when the font is smaller (as it is most of the time it is used and as it is in Visual Studio 2012) that it looks terrible.

## Microsoft's New Coke Error

When Coca-Cola Co. tested their New Coke product back in the 80s they gave people a shot-glass sized taste.  People picked it in blind taste tests over Pepsi in large percentages.   Coke thought they had killed Pepsi.  Release the New Coke and everyone will like it better than Pepsi. They released it and everyone hated it.  What?
The problem was that they had made New Coke much sweeter.  In the small shot-glass size everyone liked it better, but drinking an entire can of it was sickening.  Fail!

### Segoe UI Font == New Coke

Same thing with Segoe UI font.  Looks great when you zoom in on it.  But looks terrible at normal font sizes.

Comment: Loved it because of == ,this really is a programmer's site.

Comment: It should be (Segoe UI Font == New Coke) evaluates to "true"

Comment: Segoe UI is a terrible font design. As a case In point, try "Illinois" or "|Il". Tahoma, the default in Windows XP, was better.

Answer (score 5):

It is "Segoe UI Light".

If you plan to use the font for your website, remember that you must not use this font for free. As I wanted to find a look-alike font I ran into this one:
http://www.dafont.com/weblysleek-ui.font

Hope this helps all you googler's out there.

Comment: dafont.com is a good resource for fonts and many sans-serif fonts are similar to that one. Personally I use Sanitrixie.

Comment: If you're including it as a downloaded font then obviously that's not cool but if you could just specify it in the font-family chain then that _should_ be OK.